# Relative positioning to a logo inside a fluid container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Beginner question that I don't want to set in stone at the beginning of my home page before I move on to the basic content.  I have a header conaining a fluid fluid container, a logo with a relative position from the left, and a menu I want relative to that logo, all on he same line.  My CSS is as follows:

Top container:

```
.container-fluid {
    background-color: #30302f;
    height: 90px;
}
```

Menu items to the right of the logo

```
.dropdown-menu-right a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  right: 160px;
}
```

Assure list stays on the same line

```
.container li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Logo

```
.navbar-header a {
    background-color: #30302f;
    height: 69px;
    weidth: 367px;
    position: relative;
    left: 120px;
}
```

So is there a correc method to make sure my menu always says on the same line and to the right of the logo, and maintains flexibility for changes/additions down the road as I add to the header?  (social buttons, search bar, dropdown menu for phone media, etc...)?

Comment: Any chance you could supply the working HTML and CSS in a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Also, you misspelled width on line 4 of `.navbar-header a`

Comment: Here is a fiddle I created:  https://jsfiddle.net/4e85j0sb/

Comment: I'm also having trouble with text decoration and the remnants of the list showing up above the logo as I hover.

Comment: New fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4e85j0sb/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was to do this using twitter bootstrap as your tags suggest then you really don't need to write all of that custom css because bootstrap comes with a of that functionality built in. For more details I'd checkout bootstrap's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

Example
[image: Screenshot of the code below in Chrome]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need to customize the colors, the text decorations, the on hovers, and have the lists positioned relative to the logo.  Do I make those changes in boostrap or create an overriding CSS file of my own?

Comment: Ideally you want to leave Bootstrap as is and create a separate stylesheet for your custom rules. I would avoid overwriting any bootstrap rules and just add new classes to achieve your desired results.

Comment: New classes?  Or just stylize existing classes suppored in boostrap?

Comment: Try to keep to new classes so you have fewer conflicts.

Comment: Added a safe class into a new fiddle and styled it with poor results.  I think I am off on tightening the classes:  https://jsfiddle.net/4e85j0sb/1/

Comment: Could you include all of the css in the jsfiddle because I can't see your file and it would help to have an image of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75751/discussion-between-jean-pierre-and-jason).